# Perl script to create a SSH session to a remote machine using Putty and execute commands from a Windows machine

Tags: perl, putty

I want to create an SSH session to a remote machine using Perl, and execute commands automatically from a Windows machine. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Why use `Putty` instead of the `Net::SSH` module?

Comment: @Barmar,
I tried using the Net::SSH module, but had problems installing it. Moreover I need to save the putty logs for analysis purposes

Comment: Why Perl? Why not batch file or powershell?

Comment: How to use `putty` is not a programming question. This belongs on Super User. // `putty` does not accept a command from the command line. A command to execute on connect can be placed in a profile, though. That will only be useful to you always want to execute the same command.

Comment: @LenJaffe: Why batch file or powershell? Why not Perl? Windows shell support is hideous.

Comment: @Barmar: Windows has no native `ssh` utility, which is how `Net::SSH` does its thing.

Comment: @Borodin why? Because the OP did explain what perl was doing beyond starting putty. Using perl/ruby/python just to execute system() is overkill and means that in order to effectively catch stderr and stdout, you have to use IPC::Open2 or IPC::Open3 which adds even more complexity.  I've seen too many perl and ruby scripts that should have been shell scripts to not ask the question.

Comment: @LenJaffe: Maybe, however all that `cmd` (and, as far as I know, `PowerShell`) is capable of is starting Putty. It is a long way from being able to *"execute commands automatically"*, unless that entails just passing a fixed list of commands

Comment: Given a complete lack of commands to execute in the original post, I inferred that OP intended to us SSH com run commands on the remote server.  Goven that the IP address above is non-routable, it sands to reason that one would write script to do all the processing on the remote machine, and then invoke it via ssh, rather than building out an expect script.  Lack of detail on OP's part leads to questions on our part.

Comment: use Net::SSH2 or/and Net::SSH::Any

Answer (score 2):

The `Net::SSH` module relies on a command-line `ssh` tool, which Windows doesn't have straight from the box.

I suggest you use Putty's `plink` command instead of `putty` itself, as `plink` is much closer to an `ssh` command-line utility and is intended for this sort of thing. Together with [`IPC::Open3`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aOpen3) (or [`IPC::Open2`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aOpen2) if you're not interested in seeing the output to STDERR) it will let you `print` commands and and `readline` the responses interactively. I am sure you can create your own log files.

Alternatively you could consider [`Net::SSH::W32Perl`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aW32Perl), which is a compatibility layer around [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl). It is rather old but should be better than relying on Putty.